# MySqlProtocolException: Packet received out-of-order. Expected 1; got 3

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

При первом заходе на сайт ничего не происходит, но если зайти в вещь и в последствии вернуться, то возникает ошибка:

```
MySqlProtocolException: Packet received out-of-order. Expected 1; got 3.
```

Посмотрев через дебагер, нашел корень проблемы, но не знаю, как его решить.

То есть, MySql выдает ошибку:

```
Cannot Open when State is Connecting.
```

MySql находится на сервере, и подключаюсь к нему по IP и пользователю с правами администратора.

У меня есть вариант решения проблемы, но не хотелось бы делать костыль, ибо я думаю есть нормальный метод решения данной проблемы.

Код контроллера, в котором находится ошибка:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchName, string[] Type)
{
    var item = from i in _context.Items
               select i;
    if (Type.Length > 0)
    {
        item = item.Where(o => o.Id == -1);
        foreach (var i in Type)
        {
            var type = from items in _context.Items
                       join itemTypes in _context.ItemTypes on items.Id equals itemTypes.ItemId
                       join types in _context.Types on itemTypes.TypeId equals types.Id
                       where (types.Name == i)
                       select items;
            item = item.Union(type);
        }
        var test = from items in _context.Items
                   select items;
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName))
    {
        item = item.Where(o => o.Name.Contains(searchName));
    }
    return View(item.OrderByDescending(o => o.Top).ThenBy(o => o.Id).Take(30));
}
```

Код из подключения MySql Program:

```
ar connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options
                    .UseMySql(
                        connectionString, 
                        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 34))
                    ));
            builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config =>
            {
                config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.Database.Migrate();
            });
```

Код из Views:

```
@model IEnumerable<SPF.Models.Items.Item>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

}
```

Comment: У вашего метода `Index` сигнатура `async Task<>`. Меж тем внутри этот метод не является асинхронным. / Причина ошибки явно в неправильном использовании асинхронности. Где-то забыт `await`. / Кстати, попробуйте просто убрать `async Tack<>`, оставив только `IActionResult`.

Comment: Данный способ не помог, я добавил его при попытке пофиксить данную ошибку

Comment: Добавьте `.ToList()`

Comment: Не помогло, проблема вообще не в добавлении .ToList(), мне MySql возвращает ошибку "Cannot Open when State is Connecting.", что .ToList, что класс, ошибка от этого никуда не денется

Comment: Я не спец по мускулю; поиск показывает, что похожая ошибка часто бывает; причины неясны. / Я с вероятностью 99% считаю, что причиной является забытый где-то `await`.

Comment: `.ToList()` или `.ToArray()` практически обязателен. Запрос нужно материализовать перед подачей во View. Хотя, кто его знает, какой тип принимает ваша Вьюха; хотелось бы видеть. И хотелось бы знать, что там во вью делается с данными. Может быть, ленивая загрузка (lazy loading), не?

Comment: Сейчас сделаю поправку и добавлю код из Views

Comment: Просто по факту, я вообще убрал async и await, и ошибка как была так и осталась, я читал на чьем-то GitHub и они добавили `async` и `await` и у них это решило проблему, а мне не помогло, потом наткнулся на один пост тут и там был совет поставить `Pooling=false`, в целом это конечно решило проблему, но если есть какое-то более грамотное решение я готов его изучить и заменить мой вариант. И вопрос по поводу `.ToList()` и `.ToArray()`, если они ускоряют работу программы или так более грамотно делать то возьму на заметку. Ибо я пока что даже не junior

Answer (score 0):

Изменил строку подключения с:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=***;Database=***;Uid=***;pwd=***"
```

На:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=***;Database=***;Uid=***;pwd=***;Pooling=false"
```

Comment: Отключение пула подключений - не очень хорошая история. Как решение сиюминутной проблемы ОК, но я советую дальше исследовать.

Comment: Я даже не знаю как это сделать правильно, я испробовал очень много разных способов, и принял решение либо перенести все на mssql либо оставить mysql, ибо при работе с mssql данной ошибки не возникало